# How does pip work under virtual environments?

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

After learning how to code Python I'm starting to learn and figure out how to structure projects and set virtual environments up, but I can't make my mind up on how are packages managed when the virtual environment is activated. To make an example: I want to make a Django project. So, first of all, `mkdir` the project folder, `cd` into it and then execute `python -m venv [whatever]`. `cd` into Scripts folder and execute 'activate'. Then, `pip install Django` and `pip list` and shows Django. At last, I deactivate the virtual environment and make `pip list` again. Why is Django listed there? Should it?

Comment: Don't `cd` into the Scripts directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute"? You need to *source* `activate`: `. [whatever]/bin/activate`. If you did it correctly, `which pip` should show `[whatever]/bin/pip`, not (say) `/usr/bin/pip`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, activating the virtual environment is a convenience. You can run `[whatever]/bin/pip install Django` directly.

Comment: Well @chepner, I use Windows, so I can run the script without needing source before. Also, @sytech is right; going into Scripts is what messed this. After going to another place `pip list` showed another modules installed, which it had to show.

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed Django both inside and outside the venv (outside being the system python installation). Deactivate the venv and run `pip uninstall django` then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally I understood what was happening and I didn't realize. On one hand, virtual environments are completely independent from the global or system, so what is being installed in one side it shouldn't affect the other. On the other hand, what happened was, that for being inside the Scripts folder, when trying to execute Python commands I was actually executing the scripts with the same name, which are copies to use with the virtual environment and which can be used calling the "activate" script. There was actually no problem, it was me messed up.

Thanks to all contributors for their help.